# How do I point to a specific directory using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Note: I cant use apache "virtualhosts" on my server, but I can use mod_rewrite.

I have two domains pointing to the same IP address.

They both go to the directory `/public_html/www/`.

What is the best way to make the "home" directory of one of the domains `/public_html/www/somethingelse/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a shared-hosting plan: there are generally domain redirect tools provided to you which will allow you to point additional domains to existing paths under your main account:

domain 1:  /public_html/www

domain 2:  /public_html/www/domain2

domain 3:  /public_html/www/domain3

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root add these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/somethingelse%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/somethingelse%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somethingelse/$1 [L]
```